# What Is the Use Of ( \r ) carriage return in c program

Tags: c, carriage-return

Can You Explain Me This Code ....
 What Is The Use Of \r In This Program

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    void main()
    {

       printf("This Is \r Amarendra Deo");

    }
```

Comment: Carriage Return is a control character. It is not some special feature of the C programming language.

Answer (score 3):

The `\r` has no inherit meaning for the C language, but terminals (aka console) can react to this character in different ways. The most common way for terminal is that *carriage return* sets the cursor at the start of the current line. So when you execute this line, you'll get

```
 Amarendra Deo
```

Because `printf` will print `This Is` and the `\r` will set the cursor back to the beginning of the line and `Amarendra Deo` will overwrite whatever has been printed on that line. And since `Amarendra Deo` is longer than `This Is`, all you see is

```
 Amarendra Deo
```

This is for example a very useful trick for when you want to print something
repeatedly on the same line, for example a status message:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    printf("Processing task %d...\r", i+1);
    fflush(stdout);

    execute_task(i); // can take several seconds to finish
}
```

In that case you'll see the the `Processing task ...` text on the same line and it's a nice visual feature for the user. Try executing that for yourself (change the `execute_task(i)` with `sleep(1)` or something to make a delay).